# Soundness Theorem in reverse mathematics

Tags: reverse-math

STPL  :=  soundness theorem for predicate logic

(see [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=Y87XKUfGlCUC&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=predicate+logic+soundness+theorem&source=bl&ots=9-5JeqFp2v&sig=4iCLsI8m6RQWQ5QV7lslsGlzWZo&hl=en&ei=EYQyTYuSOYPQsAOPqdGDBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&sqi=2&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=predicate%20logic%20soundness%20theorem&f=false))

When trying to figure out the strength of the STPL in reverse mathematics, I managed to convince myself of the following:

a)  [ACA0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#Arithmetical_comprehension_ACA0) has a (provably) $\Delta_1^1$ pair of formulas, which it proves enough about to consider them as defining in it the truth predicate for first-order structures.

b)  ACA0 does not prove the STPL using the truth predicate as defined in (a).

c)  [ACA0 + [$\Delta_1^1$ induction]]  does prove the STPL as given in (b).

(EDIT: Based on François's answer, I now believe that I was wrong about (a).  First, the two formulas I was thinking of aren't provably equivalent; second, the $\Sigma_1^1$ formula, which comes closer to working, does not provably satisfy ($\operatorname{True}(\lnot p) \leftrightarrow \lnot \operatorname{True}(p))$).

So, my questions are:

1.  Are my understandings correct?

2.  Does ACA0 + STPL prove $\Delta_1^1$ induction?

3.  Is anything else known about the positions of STPL and $\Delta_1^1$ induction in the reverse mathematics hierarchy?  (For example, where would they go on the list on page 4 [here](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aMjNqd-Egj2QJ%3aests.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/neeman-luminy2010.pdf+reverse+math+reversal+%22provably+necessary%22&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&pg=4&srcid=ADGEESiNJkrHvNYXW17Wpj6EeANSdJWjmfSzU7C-XFqU4U8x7PWuMVib9q89UfdAxTfH7lgp10bMs0Hp6eYqYZVe8tZe2G4uvacFmbsVL9jdldCc91btak5Bxby5a1pbJBwUpjkWZ9xF&sig=AHIEtbTmRPmQs11tFQM8K3Eb1qeIgKv5Xg)?)

Comment: Would you need the truth predicate for arithmetic? I haven't thought carefully about what STPL would really look like in the language of second-order arithmetic, but aren't the extralogic symbols given as sets? I.e it only needs a truth predicate for logical symbols plus some extra symbols, not successor, addition, multiplication. This sounds like it ought to be simpler than Delta-1-1. 

Comment: Excellent point re arithmetic.  (fixing that now)

Comment: Somewhat along the lines of Daniel's comment: some forms of STPL, at least, are provable already in RCA0 (as in II.8 of Simpson's _SOSOA_).

Comment: About the rest of Daniel's comment, a truth predicate has to be for all (codes of) first-order formulas, not just atomic formulas.

Comment: I don't think STPL proves $\Delta^1_1$-induction, since it looks like STPL is provable in $ACA_0^+$. (Because $ACA_0^+$ is strong enough to comprehend the truth predicate for a model.)

Comment: I think your point is that $ACA_0^+$ is strong enough to *form the truth set* for the model, because I think $ACA_0$ can "comprehend the truth predicate" for the model.  Furthermore, it's not obvious (to me) that $ACA_0^+$ doesn't prove $\Delta_1^1$ induction.  Is there an online reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a caveat: Simpson treats the Soundness Theorem in SOSOA, but not in the way you intend it. Simpson defines (II.8.3) a model $M$ as having a truth valuation for all sentences in the language of $M$ augmented with a constant for each element of $M$. When models are defined in this way, the Soundness Theorem is provable in RCA<sub>0</sub> (II.8.8).

Now, you probably define a model in the usual manner: a set of elements together with an interpretation for each function symbol and relation symbol of the language. This is much weaker and it requires some work to go from such a traditional model to a full model in Simpson's sense. The fact that every traditional model can be extended to a full model is equivalent to ACA<sub>0</sub><sup>+</sup> (ACA<sub>0</sub> plus the assertion that every set has an ω-th Turing jump). Thus the Soundness Theorem (for traditional models) is provable in ACA<sub>0</sub><sup>+</sup>.

That said, ACA<sub>0</sub>' (ACA<sub>0</sub> plus the assertion that every set has a $n$-th Turing jump for every internal number $n$) proves that partial truth valuations exist: for every (internal code for a) formula $\sigma$ there is a truth valuation for all substitution instances of subformulas of $\sigma$. (ACA<sub>0</sub> only proves this for every *standard* formula $\sigma$.) So the Soundness Theorem for traditional models is actually provable in ACA<sub>0</sub>'.

In fact, the Soundness Theorem for traditional models is precisely equivalent to ACA<sub>0</sub>' over ACA<sub>0</sub>. First observe that ACA<sub>0</sub> is strong enough to prove the uniqueness (but not the existence) of partial truth valuations as described above. So it is reasonable to define the satisfaction relation for a traditional model $M$ as usual: $M \vDash \sigma$ iff there is a partial truth valuation for $\sigma$ that assigns value true to $\sigma$. The fact that this relation satisfies $M \vDash \sigma\lor\lnot\sigma$ for every $\sigma$ is then precisely equivalent to the existence of partial truth valuations for every $\sigma$. In turn, the existence of such partial truth valuations for the first-order part of a model of ACA<sub>0</sub> augmented with a predicate for the set $X$ is precisely equivalent to the existence of the $n$-th Turing jump of $X$ for every internal number $n$. Note that this reversal is a little weak since it relies on a particular definition of the satisfaction relation, but I can't think of any other reasonable definition.